# How to grab integers in a django url with a regex

Tags: python, regex, django

I tried to use `(?P<id_user>\d+)` to grab integers from my url. But it gives me a string. Any ideas how to solve it? I only need the integer `4` for my id_user.

Here's my urls.py snippet:

```
url(r'^adm/list_users/assign_user_groups/(?P<id_user>\d+)/grant_user_group/(?P<id_group>\d+)/$', views.grant_user_group, name='grant_user_group'),
```

This is the error that gave me:

```
ValueError at /adm/list_users/assign_user_groups/4/grant_user_group/2/

invalid literal for int() with base 10: '4/grant_user_group/2'
```

Edit:

Here's my urls.py code:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from adm import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^adm/list_users/$', views.list_users, name='list_users'),
    url(r'^adm/list_users/add_user/$', views.add_user, name='add_user'),
    url(r'^adm/list_users/modify_user/(?P<id_user>.*)/$', views.modify_user, name='modify_user'),
    url(r'^adm/list_users/delete_user/(?P<id_user>.*)/$', views.delete_user, name='delete_user'),
    url(r'^adm/list_users/visualize_user/(?P<id_user>.*)/$', views.visualize_user, name='visualize_user'),
    url(r'^adm/list_users/assign_user_groups/(?P<id_user>.*)/$', views.assign_user_groups, name='assign_user_groups'),
    url(r'^adm/list_users/assign_user_groups/(?P<id_user>\d+)/grant_user_group/(?P<id_group>\d+)/$', views.grant_user_group, name='grant_user_group'),
    #url(r'^adm/list_users/assign_user_groups/(?P<id_user>.*)/deny_user_group/(?P<id_group>.*)/$', views.deny_user_group, name='deny_user_group'),
    url(r'^adm/create_group/$', views.create_group, name='create_group'),
    url(r'^adm/list_groups/$', views.list_groups, name='list_groups'),
    url(r'^adm/list_groups/(?P<id_group>.*)/assign_perm/$', views.assign_permissions, name='assign_perm'),
    url(r'^adm/list_groups/(?P<id_group>.*)/grant_perm/(?P<id_perm>.*)$', views.grant_permissions, name='grant_perm'),
    url(r'^adm/list_groups/(?P<id_group>.*)/deny_perm/(?P<id_perm>.*)$', views.deny_permissions, name='deny_perm'),
)
```

Comment: Are there any other patterns beginning with `adm/list_users/assign_user_groups/`? Could you show them?

Comment: There is my urls.py code @LudwikTrammer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django always uses **the first** pattern that matches. For urls like `/adm/list_users/assign_user_groups/4/grant_user_group/2/` the pattern that matches is the one named `assign_user_groups`, and `grant_user_group` is never used.

The problem is your use of `.*` in `assign_user_groups`, which is not specific enough, allowing all characters (including "/") - this doesn't really make sense, since you want to capture only numbers.

You could reverse the order of those two patterns, but what you should do is to make them more specific, changing all occurrences of `.*` to `\d+`.